# Repeating series of numbers-unique id needed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am having an issue I have been working on from past 3 days but unable to find any solution to it.

[image: How to get to the output?]

I am having a series of repeating numbers in Column A.

The sequence in Column A basically is: 1,2,1,3,1,2...

Column C comes this way: It follows sequence 1,2,1,3,1,2. 1=A,2=A,1=B,3=A,1=C,2=B

I need to get the output as in column C (extreme challenge for me).

Post which I will concatenate the result from columns A and C to get column D (this is the easy part).

I have approx 50,000 rows in my data set and it is impossible to do it manually :(

Apologies if this question has been discussed before. Was unable to find the solution thus posted.

Thanks a ton for reading!

---

Additional info: The max value found in column A=6, the exact sequence is: 1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1,1,2 (expected corresponding sequence in column C is: A,A,B,A,C,A,D,A,E,A,F,G,B)

Comment: Okay.. I think I can see the pattern now. What is the maximum value that might be found in Column A?

Comment: The max value found in column A=6, the exact sequence is: 1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1, 1,2 (expected corresponding sequence in column C is: A,A,B,A,C,A,D,A,E,A,F,G,B)

Comment: The sequence 1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1, 1,2  repeats multiple times in the entire spreadsheet. Approx 4500 times.

Comment: You have not completely explained the pattern.  Until you do,  this Q is unanswerable and should be closed

Comment: The pattern is there @chrisneilsen . It's not explained well, but if you look you can see it. The first instance of a block of 1's gets an 'A' on each row. The second gets a 'B', the third a 'C'. Equally, he first instance of a block of 2's gets an 'A'. The second gets a 'B', the third a 'C'... and on and on.

Comment: @clr that's what I thought until the OP posted their "additional info" which breaks that pattern.  Maybe there is an error in that info and the pattern is in fact correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doable with formulas and and helper column:

In column E (Helper): `=IF(A2=A1,"",A2)`

In Column C (Output): `=IF(E2="",C1,CHAR(COUNTIF($E$2:E2,E2)+64))`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This ought to do it:

```
Sub write_column_C()
    Dim num(6)
    Dim lastnum As Long
    Dim c As Range

    lastnum = 0

    With Worksheets("YourSheetNameHere")
        For Each c In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
            If c.Value <> lastnum Then
                num(c.Value) = num(c.Value) + 1
            End If
            lastnum = c.Value
            c.Offset(0, 2) = Chr(64 + num(c.Value))
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```